# button without the form is semantic?

Tags: html, markup

In html5 can I use `<button>` outside the `<form>`, like this:

```
<body>
    <form action="page.html" method="get" id="myForm">
    ...
    </form>
    <button type="submit" form="myForm" value="Submit">Send</button>
</body>
```

But I do not want to use the form, only the `<button>`, because my project is all done with Javascript/Ajax

I wanted to make a "noscript-friendly" design, but it is a closed intranet and for a company project and do not have much time for this.

Use `<button>` without `<form>` is semantic?

```
<body>
    <div>
        <button type="button">test</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Or would be better to continue to use `<a href="javascript:void(0)">`?

> Note: Remember not all valid code by W3 is a semantic code

Comment: I don't know about WEB-semantics, but you can certainly use buttons outside a form in all major browsers. Just declare type='button' to make sure the type does not default to 'submit' in case you have a form on your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the `button` element is appropriate.

That’s why there is the [Button state](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/forms.html#attr-button-type-button-state) in the first place. The HTML5 spec also shows an [example](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/forms.html#attr-button-type-button-state), very similar to your use case:

> The following button is labeled "Show hint" and pops up a dialog box when activated:
>
> ```
> <button type=button
>     onclick="alert('This 15-20 minute piece was composed by George Gershwin.')">
>  Show hint
> </button>
> ```

---

Note: Your question has nothing to do with the [Semantic Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web). There is a difference between "semantic (markup)" and "Semantic Web".

Your use of the `button` element is "semantic" in the sense that you are using it correctly according to the HTML5 specification, and that there is no other element defined which would be more appropriate.

You might want to use the [`a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) in cases where you are navigating to another resource (no matter how it’s implemented technically). For apps, the difference is sometimes not very clear. A rule of thumb: if the URL changes (could users want to bookmark/share it?) and/or you could use a [link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#linkTypes) (even only theoretically), it’s likely that you should use `a` instead of `button`. But as this is a different question, please take it just as a side note.

Comment: I edit my question. Thanks for the explanation of the semantics!

Comment: their response was not quite what I was looking for, but the link helped me find the following passage: "Submit Button: If the element has a form owner, the element must submit the form owner from the button element.  Reset Button: If the element has a form owner, the element must reset the form owner.", in others words the "IF" in text makes clear that it is not necessary to "FORM".